# Prevent update/delete in stored procedure having dynamic queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, policy

There's one stored procedure which executes a dynamic queries which will be from parameter. The dynamic queries mostly contains just SELECT statement but may contain delete/update some time.

I want to raise errors when this procedure tries to run the dynamic query which has DELETE or UPDATE commands.
Eg..

---

```
create procedure spa_test

@sql varchar(2000)
AS
EXEC(@sql)
go
----------------------

SET @sql1 = ' DELETE FROM data_table where .... ;
                    ......... 
                    SELECT * FROM some_table ..  '

SET @sql2 = '....
                    ......... 
                    SELECT * FROM some_table   '


EXEC spa_test @sql1 -- should result in error
EXEC spa_test @sql2 -- no error and procedure runs successfully
```

---

Can I accomplish this by using SQL Server Policy management ? 
I can not alter this procedure spa_test and can not change the privilege of user running it.
Is there any other way I can accomplish this need ?

Comment: Can you add your own SP, that will run before spa_test and raise errors?

Comment: Or rename the real `spa_test` and wrap it in a new `spa_test` proc which does the checks (e.g. as per @mhasan's answer)

Comment: Make your table readonly so no one can update or delete record...without altering the SP this is the only way i know in SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

You can use CHARINDEX() to search for DELETE , UPDATE expression in your `@sql` query.

```
CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind ,expressionToSearch)
```

-

```
IF (CHARINDEX(@sql1 , 'DELETE FROM') <> 0 or CHARINDEX(@sql1 , 'UPDATE') <> 0 )
   RAISERROR(...)
ELSE
   EXEC(@sql1)
```

Comment: This is to be checked while calling the stored procedure , check the paramater being passed beforehand